# Sending a multidimensional array through pipe from child proc to parent

Tags: c, pipe

I'm trying to send a bi-dimensional array from a child process to a parent process and failing terribly. Not exactly sure how this should be done but here's what I tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fd[2];
int matrix[2][2];

int main () {

  pipe (fd);
  if (0 == fork()) {
    printf ("Start child process with pid: %d\n", getpid());
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      matrix[i][i] = 1;

    write (fd[1], matrix, 4);
    exit (0);
  }

  printf ("Start parent process with pid: %d\n", getpid());
  read (fd[0], matrix, 4);
  printf ("Received %d\n", matrix[1][1]);

return 0;
}
```

Compiles correctly but the received value is always 0 instead of 1.
What am I doing wrong ? (lots of things, I expect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are misunderstanding the third argument of `read` and `write`
to be number of elements. `read` and `write` system calls require their [third argument](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) to be count of bytes.

Change your code

```
write (fd[1], matrix, 4);
...
read (fd[0], matrix, 4);
```

to

```
write (fd[1], matrix, 4*sizeof(int));
...
read (fd[0], matrix, 4*sizeof(int));
```